# How to detect rows without content?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wanted to know how to get the rows in excel without content.
Let's say for example,
[image]

I want to get the total (overall total) of all the pieces found in column B but only those rows in column B without equivalent PCS in column C will be summed up.
On the example above, the total is 1,500 because 800 and 700 do not have an equivalent PCS in column C, therefore 800 and 700 were summed up.

Is there any possible way to create a formula to get 1,500? How can I detect the rows in column C with no content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function designed for these situations is `SUMIF`:

`=SUMIF(D3:D6,"",B3:B6)`